# Is there a term for nouns used as adjectives?

Tags: gerunds, terminology, attributive-nouns

I know that a verb used as a noun is called a *gerund*. An example (from American baseball) is a "run," or a "home run," where a "run" across the plate scores a point. "Run" is the gerund.

In the term "home run," home is a noun used as an adjective for the gerund run. Is there a grammatical term that describes "home" in this context, i.e. a noun used as an adjective?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To begin with, *run* in the phrase *a home run* is not a gerund. A gerund is an *-ing* form employed as a noun or as head of a clause acting as a noun. It maintains many properties of a verb: for instance, it may take objects, and it may be modified by adverbs.

> Be particularly careful in ***running*** machinery you are not familiar with.
>   ***Running*** swiftly will tire you out.

*Run* in *home run* is simply a noun derived from the verb *run*. It does not take objects, and it is not modified by adverbs.

> <sup>∗</sup> Be particularly careful in **run** machinery you are not familiar with.
>   <sup>∗</sup>  **Run** swiftly will tire you out.

A noun employed as a modifier on another noun, like *home* in *home run*, is called an ***attributive*** noun. Some more examples:

- ***home*** improvement
- ***noun*** phrase
- ***grammar*** book
- ***lunch*** box
- ***flight*** attendant

Comment: I'd believe *running shoes* as a "gerund functioning as adjective", but *running machinery* just looks like a continuous verb form to me. Same for *running swiftly*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers What if we make a little change: "I hate his running machinery he's not familiar with"?

Comment: I think you're more the expert on terminology, but I suppose I'd have to admit the possessive ***his*** means it must be a noun, therefore it must be a gerund, not a participle. The question then arises whether we can/should parse *"I hate running machinery"* as parallel to *"I hate **me** being poor"* or *"I hate **my** being poor"*. To which I don't know the answer - I just thought there must be more "clear-cut" examples of gerunds than your first two.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The last is a good point. I'll revise. ... as for the terminology, there's folks out there that sidestep the question and call it a gerund-participle. I follow the old use and call it a gerund when it heads a clause that acts as an NP and a participle when it heads a clause that acts as an adjective; but it doesn't lose its 'verbal' (rhemic) quality in either case.